# find command suppressing messages

Tags: bash, unix, find

whenever i execute find command for searching for some file

like

```
find . -name "abc"
```

specially from the root,it displays lots of "`cannot open` or `cannot search` "

how can suppress those messages?is there any flag for that?

Answer (score 4):

You can direct the standard error stream to `/dev/null`, viz:

```
find . -name "abc" 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

you can suppress by piping stderr(2) to `/dev/null` or to a log file for later viewing

```
find . -name "abc" 2>/dev/null
find . -name "abc" 2>/errorlog.txt
```